# Providing Date and Human Readable timestamps in a Python Script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking for some examples to utilize in a Geoprocessing Python script I have. What I am having issues with is getting a set of time stamps to log to a file I am using for reporting.

I have used the Logging module, but it is not working for me. so I have since decided to use the "open()" method.

I am using this currently: 
strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p")

The issue I am having is that the only time stamp I get the same time stamp in every occurrence I have a stamp set up to track a specific process.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. Could you describe more precisely what you expect to happen and what happens instead? Maybe you could also include a specific example.

Comment: Well then either post the solution or delete this question, because it's currently useless to anyone else in its current form.

Comment: Yes ma'am. It's being deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a one-second resolution time stamp with the format you provided:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

def get_timestamp():
    format_str = "%A, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p"
    result = datetime.now().strftime(format_str)
    return result

print get_timestamp()
time.sleep(1)
print get_timestamp()
```

**Output**

```
Thursday, 27 Apr 2017 17:41:46 PM
Thursday, 27 Apr 2017 17:41:47 PM
```